# RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded after using .map

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to show the list of todos but having trouble with Maximum call stack size exceeded after using .map. Can someone tell me what the problem is?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './todo.css';

export default class Todo extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { todos: ['to do one thing', 'to do another thing'] };
  }

  showTodos() {
    return this.state.todos.map((todo) => (
      <Todo key={todo} todo={todo} />
    ));
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div className={'container'}>
        {this.showTodos()}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: How does your `Todo` component look like? also you need to bind `this.showTodos` with `this`, change `this.showTodos()` with `this.showTodos.bind(this)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you are rendering the Todo element itself in your showTodos() method, so you try to render a list of Todo list of Todo list of Todo list,...

Instead, render a new div element like this :

```
  showTodos() {
    return this.state.todos.map((todo) => (
      <div key={todo}>{todo}</div>
    ));
  }
```

Comment: but when I'm doing like this i have only one div with all todos and I need as many divs as todos